# Missing Wifi interface after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, catalina

So I took the plung and upgraded my Late 2013 Macbook pro from Mojave to Catalina. Everything else "seemed" okay apart from the fact that I had no wifi. The icon was greyed out. I tried all the usual advice, SMC and NVPRAM/PRAM resets. I even deleted the Network plist file but still the wifi icon was greyed out and from the System Information App all I had under Network -> Wi-Fi was:

```
  Software Versions:
  CoreWLAN: 13.0 (null)
  CoreWLANKit:  13.0 (null)
  Menu Extra:   13.0 (null)
  System Information:   12.0 (null
  IO80211 Family:   12.0 (null)
  Diagnostics:  1.0 (null)
  AirPort Utility:
```

In the Network app, the Wifi interface isn't listed when I tried to manually create the wifi entry. In the end I was ready to take my Macbook pro for repairs as I believed that my wifi interface was fried. Then I decided to downgrade back to Mojave and it worked perfectly.

I tried the upgrade again up to Catalina and the wifi problem showed up again. So now I'm back on Mojave. The supprise for me is according to Apple model of Macbook pro is supported by Catalina so I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a 2015 MBP 13"...

Comment: I asked here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250720965

Comment: I have same issue. Anyone find the solution?

Comment: Facing the same issue also with a Late 2013 MBP 13"

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti have you made any progress with your issue? I'm still back on Mojave as a result. It was such a pain getting my machine back up to scratch wouldn't want to risk is again.

Comment: No, Apple contacted me to run some diagnostics but I downgraded and won't have time for a while to upgrade, do that and downgrade again in case it's still broken

Comment: Same issue here, any solution ? How can I roll back with no WiFi and no backup?

Comment: @MattBlack in my case I had a backup. However as I didn't have access to any other Mac pc and as such no internet connection to my MacBook Pro, I ordered a usb-to-ethernet adaptor from Amazon. I then used an ethernet cable to connect the laptop to the internet. Then I downloaded and created a bootable Mojave installer usb stick which I used to reinstall on my MacBook Pro. Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! this is such a pain :(

Comment: Came here with desperation...Macbook Pro 2016 15" 13,3... Wireless just stopped working. Still connects, to the access point, but does not acquire an IP. I also have the CoreWLAN 13.0 ((null)) situation under the system information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to Giovanni Caporaletti for posting and referencing this issues on the apple communities forum. I've as at today been able to update to Catalina and have wifi working. The solution can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250720965?answerId=251753760022#251753760022)

but to prevent it being lost for whatever reason I'll repost it below:

> - [Download the modified files](https://workupload.com/file/cxdjhdk9BpN) (thanks Alex!) and unzip > you get a
>   folder named WiFi_kexts.
> - Boot into Recovery Mode: restart your computer while pressing and holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
> - Open Utilities > Terminal via Menu Bar.
> - Type `csrutil disable` and hit return
> - Type reboot and hit return > computer reboots normally
> - Open Utilities > Terminal and enter `cd` and hit the space bar (don't hit return)
> - Drag the folder WiFi_kexts onto the Terminal window and hit return.
> - In Terminal, enter `sudo mount -uw /` and hit return, then enter your user password and hit return.
> - Enter `sudo cp -r IO80211Family.kext /System/Library/Extensions/` and hit return
> - Enter `sudo cp -r IO80211FamilyV2.kext /System/Library/Extensions/` and hit return
> - Right-click on Kext Utility in the folder WiFi_kexts and choose open, click open in the following dialog, authenticate with your
>   password
> - Wait for Kext Utility to complete – this took maybe two minutes on my setup, and I got an error message in the end, as well as "All done"
> - Reboot your computer and enjoy Wi-Fi in Catalina
>   If you want to turn on SIP again you can boot into recovery mode again and enter `csrutil enable` (hit return) `reboot` (hit return)

In summary I had to get the Wi-Fi kexts from Mojave, copy it to `/System/Library/Extensions` and then run the Kext Utility to do its thing after which I had my Wi-Fi back.

Comment: So with the recent upgrade to Catalina 10.15.2, I lost my Wi-Fi interface again and had to repeat the above steps to get it back. I don't know why Apple have decided to remove kexts from Catalina.

Comment: It's like a magic. It worked on macbook pro 2015 mid

Comment: @Napoleon I think the download link is no longer active. Could you please fix that? You're my only hope...Apple let me down big time. What a disappointment.

Comment: @JonathanKomar the link is working fine for me. I've just downloaded the file again. If you're still having problems I don't mind emailing it to you.

Comment: It works on my macbook pro 2015 mid. i am totally surprised

Comment: Has anyone tried to see if this fix will work on Big Sur?

Comment: Unfortunately this fix doesn't work. Because as of Big Sur apple in their wisdom have decided to lock the macs down even more by sealing off `/System` and any folder under it so the command `sudo mount -uw /` fails with a permission error. There are a few work arounds but none has worked for me yet.

Comment: I had this problem on Catalina and managed to fix it using above steps. Updated to Big Sur no problem. Then I had to reset PRAM and all wifi settings were gone. Thought updating to Monterey would fix the issue automatically. It wasn't. Above fix didn't work as the root partition was not writable. After days of digging, I managed to fix it by copying all content from /System/Library/Extensions to /Library/Extensions also I copied the two files mentioned on above fix and ran the kext utility. After rebooting wifi issue was fixed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Updated to catalina overnight and in the morning wifi was not working. I reinstalled catalina from Recovery again. Now wifi is working even though System Information App still shows (null) for Network -> Wifi entries