# MacBook Pro (Mid-2014) 15": Wifi Stopped Working after updating to MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, catalina, software-update

I have an old MacBook Pro (mid 2014). After updating from Mojave (10.14.x) to Catalina (10.15.7), Wifi Cannot turn on at all and top bar icon grayed out. I've also updated to Big Sur (11.7.10) but had same issue. Check the screenshots below for better understanding.

PS: Whenever I downgrade/restore to Mojave, Wifi start working. I have backup in time machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like some other people had a similar issue [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372025/missing-wifi-interface-after-upgrade-to-catalina); could you try their solutions and see if it works for you? Also maybe try a fresh installation to a secondary drive if you have one available.